# Why won't this done function run?

Tags: jquery

I'm just trying to refresh the page once the info is posted, which does happen successfully.  The function won't call though.

```
$('#qwerty').sortable({
    update: function (event, ui) {
        var newOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
        $.post(document.URL + '/saveEdit', {
            order: newOrder
        }).done(function () {
            console.log('Y wont this call?');
            window.location.href = document.URL;
        });
    }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/

Comment: Try `success()` instead of `done()`.

Comment: Nope that didn't do it.

Comment: Could it be because I'm redirecting the URL?

Comment: If I knew the solution I'd post an answer. That's why these are just comments. You should try easier code like this: `$.post('http:/url/saveEdit', {order:'xyz'}).done(function () { console.log('DONE!'); });`. Until this doesn't work you shouldn't even try the more complex code. Halfway through you'll probably understand the error and solve the bug :)

Comment: Does your post request even works? Do you get the response you like? have you tried using the first callback of post()? like $.post(URL, function(data){ console.log(data);})

Comment: Yeah it works perfectly.  I'm using `$('#qwerty').mouseup(function(){
 window.location.replace(document.URL);
});` which does refresh, but I'm still curious y what I wrote above doesn't work